# Spring Security UI - Disable mail sending on RegisterController

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to disable mail sending to newly registered users from [Register Spring Security UI](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui)'s [RegisterController](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/ui/RegisterController.groovy) because I do not have a mail server installed on my local machine.

I've followed the steps from [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/) all works ok, until it tried to send the registration mail.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a configurable parameter on SS UI that disables mail sending?
2. If the answer to point 1 is negative what would be the correct approach to disable that? Modify and build SS UI plugin **or** subclass [RegisterController](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/ui/RegisterController.groovy)?

Environment:

- Grails 2.4.4
- Spring Security UI 1.0-RC2
- Spring Security Core 2.0-RC4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no configuration parameter on SS UI to disable sending e-mails. The correct approach, according to the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/guide/customization.html), is to use `s2-ui-override` script. This allows you to target the package/section you want to override.

From the documentation:

> The plugin's controllers and GSPs are easily overridden using the
>   s2ui-override script. The general syntax for running the script is
>
> `grails s2ui-override <type> <controller-package>`
>
> The script will copy an empty controller that extends the
>   corresponding plugin controller into your application so you can
>   override individual actions and methods as needed. It also copies the
>   controller's GSPs. The exceptions are 'auth' and 'layout' which only
>   copy GSPs.